how to fixed Next.js app 'npm run build' show message First Load JS shared by all
I'm trying build my project but show error 'First Load JS shared by all', how to fixed it.
PS C:\Users\Devloper\client> npm run build
> solid-nextjs@0.2.0 build
> next build
  ▲ Next.js 14.2.3
Creating an optimized production build
Route (app)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                    31.8 kB         156 kB
├ ○ /_not-found                          871 B          87.9 kB
├ ○ /auth/signin                         3.51 kB         134 kB
├ ○ /auth/signup                         3.51 kB         134 kB
├ ○ /blog                                714 B           132 kB
├ ○ /blog/blog-details                   182 B            99 kB
├ ○ /docs                                552 B          94.3 kB
├ ○ /error                               175 B          92.3 kB
└ ○ /support                             1.82 kB         126 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all            87 kB
  ├ chunks/23-1892795f6819b9e1.js        31.5 kB
  ├ chunks/fd9d1056-fe292c6953b42a04.js  53.6 kB
  └ other shared chunks (total)          1.9 kB
○  (Static)  prerendered as static content



I think it's not an error.

Sir I'm new here. I want to deploy GoDaddy Server. I try to build app show message.

There is no error in your screenshot, Next.js outputs some statistics about the bundle size, but that's completely normal.
